# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int objec

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

How can I solve this error After running my code as follows . I am using the function below and implementin running window for loop on it but end up getting the error below. The for loop works and hungs at a point.

```
def get_grps(s, thresh=-1, Nmin=3):
    """
    Nmin : int > 0
    Min number of consecutive values below threshold.
    """
    m = np.logical_and.reduce([s.shift(-i).le(thresh) for i in range(Nmin)])
    if Nmin > 1:
        m = pd.Series(m, index=s.index).replace({False: np.NaN}).ffill(limit=Nmin - 1).fillna(False)
    else:
        m = pd.Series(m, index=s.index)

    # Form consecutive groups
    gps = m.ne(m.shift(1)).cumsum().where(m)

    # Return None if no groups, else the aggregations
    if gps.isnull().all():
        return 0
    else:
        agg = s.groupby(gps).agg([list, sum, 'size']).reset_index(drop=True)
        # agg2 = s2.groupby(gps).agg([list, sum, 'size']).reset_index(drop=True)
        return agg, gps


data_spi = [-0.32361498 -0.5229471   0.15702732  0.28753752   -0.01069884 -0.8163699
  -1.3169327   0.4413181   0.75815576  1.3858147   0.49990863-0.06357133
-0.78432    -0.95337325 -1.663739    0.18965477  0.81183237   0.8360347
  0.99537593 -0.12197364 -0.31432647 -2.0865853   0.2084263    0.13332903
 -0.05270813 -1.0090573  -1.6578217  -1.2969246  -0.70916456   0.70059913
 -1.2127264  -0.659762   -1.1612778  -2.1216285  -0.8054617    -0.6293912
 -2.2103117  -1.9373081  -2.530625   -2.4089663  -1.950846    -1.6129876]
lon = data_spi.lon
lat = data_spi.lat
print(len(data_spi))

n=6

for x in range(len(lat)):
    for y in range(len(lon)):
        if data_spi[0, x, y] != 0:
            for i in range(len(data_spi)-70):
                ts = data_spi[i:i+10, x, y].fillna(1)
                print(ts)
                # print(np.array(ts))

                agg, gps = get_grps(pd.Series(ts), thresh=-1, Nmin=3)

                duration = np.nanmean(agg['sum'])
                frequency = len(agg['sum'])
                severity = np.abs(np.mean(agg['sum']))
                intensity = np.mean(np.abs(agg['sum'] / agg['size']))
                print(f'intensity {intensity}')
```

I get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/mada0007/PycharmProjects/Research_ass /FREQ_MEAN_INT_DUR_CORR.py", line 80, in <module>
 agg, gps = get_grps(pd.Series(ts), thresh=-1, Nmin=3)
 typeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: replace `return 0` by `return 0, 0`, or raise an error instead of returning 0

Comment: @olinox seems to working now, could you please explain this error to me. Is it because zero is a single number so cant iterate. which part of this code is actually causing this error? Thanks

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mada0007/PycharmProjects/Research_ass/FREQ_MEAN_INT_DUR_CORR.py", line 86, in <module>
    duration = np.nanmean(agg['sum'])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
gps,0 agg 0. I still get this error after it runs for some time

Comment: Because you need to handle the case where 0 is returned. See the anwer I posted

Comment: In one case your function `get_grps()` returns a single integer: `return 0`, in another case a tuple of two integers: `return agg, gp`. This is inconsistent and returning a single integer messes up the ability of the client code to tuple-unpack the result `agg, gps = get_grps(...)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just replace `return 0` by `return 0, 0`, or better: raise an error instead of returning 0

When your `if` condition is True, you only return `0`. Then later, when you do `agg, gps = get_grps(...)`, you tell python to unpack the result of the function. Then, python is expecting a 2-length iterable, and try to unpack it, but as it says: it 'cannot unpack non-iterable int object'...

So a quick workaround is to return a tuple (0, 0) with `return 0, 0`, but it is quite bad because you return integers where objects are expected. your script will crash on the next line `duration = np.nanmean(agg['sum'])` (since `agg` is 0).

Some cleaner solutions to handle this case would be to unpack in a second time:

```
def get_grps(s, thresh=-1, Nmin=3):
    # ...
    if gps.isnull().all():
        return None
    else:
        # ...
        return agg, gps

for i in range(len(data_spi)-70):
    ts = data_spi[i:i+10, x, y].fillna(1)

    result = get_grps(pd.Series(ts), thresh=-1, Nmin=3)
    if result is None:
        break

    agg, gps = result

    duration = np.nanmean(agg['sum'])
    frequency = len(agg['sum'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar error has appeared, so to resolve this I am posting one eg. hoping it will help out.

Reason: since `int` does not have `__itr__` method inside it, we can't iterate it over like we do in `list` or `tuple` or `dict{}`.

```
x,y,z,n = input() # NOT CONVERTING THE INPUT TO 'INT' HERE  

l = []  

for a in range(0,int(x)): # converting the input to INT  
    for b in range(0,int(y)): # converting the input to INT  
        for c in range(0,int(z)): # converting the input to INT  
            if a+b+c!= n:  
                l.append([a,b,c])  
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

**(DJANGO)**
In my case, I was trying get a item without set which parameter for search:

```
 schooling = Schooling.objects.get(randint(1, 10)) #Error


 schooling = Schooling.objects.get(id=randint(1, 10)) #OK set id=
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below in Django:

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

When retrieving **id** with [get(20)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) or [filter(20)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) as shown below:

```py
                      # Here
obj = Person.objects.get(20)
```

```py
                        # Here
qs = Person.objects.filter(20)
```

So, I retrieved **id** with `get(id=20)` or `filter(id=20)` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
                       # Here
obj = Person.objects.get(id=20)
```

```py
                         # Here
qs = Person.objects.filter(id=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon running tests in my Django project, I encountered a similar error.

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I discovered a typo error in the creation of the deleteCourse function within my views.py file. The mistake was using a hyphen instead of an equal sign.

```
def deleteCourse(rqeuest,id):
    course = Course.objects.get(id-id)
    course.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

The updated version of the code is presented below for your review:

```
def deleteCourse(rqeuest,id):
    course = Course.objects.get(id=id)
    course.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

Attention to detail is key in coding. Take the time to thoroughly review your code, ensuring accuracy and correctness. It's the best defense against unexpected errors and ensures your code runs smoothly.